# How to play audio on pydroid3?

Tags: android, python-3.x, audio

I want to be able to play a simple mp3 file in pydroid3. I've installed the playsound library but it just prints out a bunch of mumbo jumbo things like "CalledProcessError" and "Returned non zero exit status 1".
Here's my code:
from playsound import playsound
import os
print(os.path.abspath("qqq.mp3"))
playsound("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/qqq.mp3")

Answer (score 1):

install kivy and
try this :

```
from android import activity
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
sound = SoundLoader.load("beep-08b.wav")
sound.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mixer of pygame
 `from pygame import mixer  mixer.init() pygame.mixer.load("source.mp3") pygame.mixer.play()`